# Getting different value in preview and response tab in chrome developer tools

Tags: angular

In an Angular Application I am trying to call a backend service which returns a JSON, When i look into the response received in the developer tools, it shows different value for "card_eid" in Response tab vs Preview tab. 
The value of card_eid is sent as an integer from Backend.

[Preview Tab Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwxhU.png)

Comment: Your image only shows `Preview` tab. Please share the different values. It could be the result of browser JavaScript precision.

Answer (score 2):

Your "card_eid" is probably more than 15 characters, for which there is a browser javascript round off. 
Convert the number to BIGINT .