# Difference in response values in the preview tab and response tab, Chrome network devtools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, pretty-print

I'm trying to get started with API Instagram Basic Display. Оne of the steps ([#5](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started?locale=en_US)) is to get an access token by making a post request to API

> ...Upon success, the API will return a JSON encoded object containing a short-lived Instagram User Access Token, valid for 1 hour, and your Instagram test user’s ID...

Using Angular HttpClient, I receive the token and ID. Token is OK, but user ID value differs by one from the correct value. User id value consists of 17 digits.
For example real id is: 1234567898123456**7**, and I receive 1234567898123456**6**

The same situation is when viewing user ID in developer tools in chrome Network->Preview tab - the value is one less than the real, but in the Network->Response tab the value is correct. MS Edge - a similar problem: in dev tools enabling "pretty print" in Response tab decreases the actual user ID value by one.
[chrome preview tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dx7a7.jpg), [chrome response tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20sCk.jpg), [edge - pretty print disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnmhE.jpg), [edge - pretty print enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgaIx.jpg).

While sending a request through postman, the answer comes with the correct value. [postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNZ5L.jpg)

Please tell me what is the reason for this behavior, and is there any way to avoid such problems?
Thank you

Comment: I also encountered the same issue, someone said that [the browser will do some number manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58452991/1500274) when the number is bigger than 15 characters. So what I'm doing is just wrap the returned field as a string to avoid the number manipulation in browser.

Answer (score 2):

This is because that javascript max safe integer is 9007199254740991 and your id is greater than that. To get the correct value you need to change it to string.